# Tkinter application becoming less responsive over time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having problems with my TKinter application when run for long periods of time. The application is simple it receives serial data through usb and prints it on the TK window. It works fine for a long time but when left for hald a day or overnight it is not responsive and I get the generic windows (not responding) error on the application bar at the top, if I try to minimise or close the window it may take up to 5~10 minutes to do it.

I do not get any errors on the python terminal window

I have changed my battery and power setting on my computer to not sleep and normal performance, still not resolved problem

I have stripped my code to the bare minimum to see if it was a section of code cousing the trouble

Here is my code posted below, hopefully some one can shed some light on this for me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import serial
import numpy 
import sys


arduinoData = serial.Serial('com7', 115200)  #Creating our serial object named arduinoData


# Main Tkinter application
class Application(Frame):

            # Init the variables & start measurements
        def __init__(self, master=None):
                Frame.__init__(self, master)
                root.title( "Dashboard")
                root.state('zoomed')

                self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
                self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)

                self.B1 = StringVar()

                self.createWidgets()
                self.pack()
                self.measure()

        # Create display elements
        def createWidgets(self):

                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=0,padx=100,pady=200)

    # Read the incoming serial data and display it
        def measure(self):

                if(arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):                               #Wait till there is data to read

                        arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()               #read serial data
                        arduinoString =str(arduinoString,'utf-8')            #Removes the surrounding rubbish

                        self.B1.set(str(arduinoString))                      #Set the label to the received arduino data 
                        self.B1DO = Label(self, textvariable=self.B1, font=('Verdana', 15)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

                arduinoData.flushOutput()                                    #Clear old data
                arduinoData.flushInput()

                self.after(1000,self.measure)                                #Wait 1 second between each measurement


# Create and run the GUI
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are perpetually creating new B1DO Labels, which could create a resource leak in your application. Try taking the `self.B1DO` definition and put it in `createWidgets` so that the Label is only created once:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import serial
import numpy 
import sys


arduinoData = serial.Serial('com7', 115200)  #Creating our serial object named arduinoData


# Main Tkinter application
class Application(Frame):

            # Init the variables & start measurements
        def __init__(self, master=None):
                Frame.__init__(self, master)
                root.title( "Dashboard")
                root.state('zoomed')

                self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
                self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)

                self.B1 = StringVar()

                self.createWidgets()
                self.pack()
                self.measure()

        # Create display elements
        def createWidgets(self):
                self.B1DO = Label(self, textvariable=self.B1, font=('Verdana', 15)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
                self.temperature = Label(self, text="", font=('Verdana', 20)).grid(row=5, column=0,padx=100,pady=200)

    # Read the incoming serial data and display it
        def measure(self):

                if(arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):                               #Wait till there is data to read

                        arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()               #read serial data
                        arduinoString =str(arduinoString,'utf-8')            #Removes the surrounding rubbish

                        self.B1.set(str(arduinoString))                      #Set the label to the received arduino data 


                arduinoData.flushOutput()                                    #Clear old data
                arduinoData.flushInput()

                self.after(1000,self.measure)                                #Wait 1 second between each measurement


# Create and run the GUI
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am going to try this out over night and i'll let you know the result.

Comment: Ok, all working fine now, I have marked this as solved and want to say thanks again for your time.